# How can I dynamically hide and shows Graphics3D objects?

Tags: manipulate, gui-construction

This quest is motivated by [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/example/DynamicallyHideAndShowPlots.html). If I wish to visualize `3` `Graphics3D` objects, I can do this:

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[{Opacity[a], Sphere[], Opacity[b], Cone[], Opacity[c], 
   Cylinder[]}, Boxed -> False],
 {{a, 1, "Sphere"}, {1, 0}},
 {{b, 1, "Cone"}, {1, 0}},
 {{c, 1, "Cylinder"}, {1, 0}},
 ControlPlacement -> Left, FrameMargins -> 0]
```

(The only problem with this is that when nothing is selected, I can still see two ellipses which I don't want.)

If I now wish to visualize say, `10` different objects, I should use an array of opacities instead of `a`, `b`, `c` and so on. While trying to do this in the following way I get an error message that

`Manipulate::vsform: Manipulate argument {{op[[1]],1,Sphere},{1,0}} does not have the correct form for a variable specification.`

The code I used is:

```
op = {0, 0, 0};
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[{Opacity[op[[1]]], Sphere[], Opacity[op[[1]]], Cone[], 
   Opacity[op[[1]]], Cylinder[]}, Boxed -> False],
 {{op[[1]], 1, "Sphere"}, {1, 0}},
 {{op[[2]], 1, "Cone"}, {1, 0}},
 {{op[[3]], 1, "Cylinder"}, {1, 0}},
 ControlPlacement -> Left, FrameMargins -> 0]
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: I don't know if it is interesting for you, but this works : `Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[{Opacity[a[1]], Sphere[], Opacity[a[2]], Cone[], Opacity[a[3]], 
   Cylinder[]}, Boxed -> False],
 {{a[1], 1, "Sphere"}, {1, 0}},
 {{a[2], 1, "Cone"}, {1, 0}},
 {{a[3], 1, "Cylinder"}, {1, 0}},
 ControlPlacement -> Left, FrameMargins -> 0]`

Comment: Also, you can specify `EdgeForm[None]` at the beginning of your `Graphics3D` list to remove those ellipses.

Answer (score 1):

```
Module[
 {pl = PolyhedronData["Archimedean"]},
 Manipulate[
  Evaluate[
   Graphics3D[
    {
     EdgeForm[None],
     Riffle[
      Array[Opacity[q[#]] &, 13],
      MapIndexed[
       Tooltip[Translate[
          First[
           PolyhedronData[#1]],
          10 {Mod[First[#2], 4], Quotient[First[#2], 4], 0}
          ], #1] &
       , pl
       ]
      ]
     }
    ]
   ]
  , Evaluate[Sequence @@ MapIndexed[{{q[First@#2], 1, #1}, 0, 1} &, pl]
   ]
  ]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a programmatic approach, which populates the `Manipulate` function with shapes from a list I called `objects`. The approach is to use `Checkbox[Dynamic[...]]` to `Pick` the items from `objects` to include in the `Graphics3D` list.

```
With[{objects = {Sphere[], Cone[], Cylinder[]}},
 Manipulate[
  Graphics3D[Pick[objects, picks, 1], Boxed -> False],
  {{picks, Table[1, {Length[objects]}]}, ControlType -> None}, 
  Dynamic[Grid[Transpose[
    {Outer[Checkbox[Dynamic[picks[[#1]]], {0, 1}] &, 
     Range[Length[objects]]], ToString@*Head /@ objects}]]
  ], ControlPlacement -> Left, FrameMargins -> 0]
]
```

[image]